# 2 different aggregates in a query, can't figure it out

Tags: sql, oracle11g

So i have this query:

```
SELECT department_id, AVG(salary)
FROM   employees
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING MAX(salary) > 10000;
```

But the output confuses me a little bit, because i just don't get it why it shows values lower than 10000, even tough i specified in the filtering clause to be > 10000

```
              8601,333333333333333333333333333333333333
              4150
              19333,3333333333333333333333333333333333
              9500
              10154
              8955,882352941176470588235294117647058824
```

I expected only 10154 and 19333,3333333333333333333333333333333333 to be outputed. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are showing the average of salaries, where the *max()* in the department is greater than 10000.  So, only one of the salaries needs to be greater than 10000 for the department to show.

Perhaps you mean:

```
SELECT department_id, MAX(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING MAX(salary) > 10000;
```

Comment: Thanks man, now i fully understand the query and its purpose, it took me some time to get it :). Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following sql -

```
SELECT department_id, AVG(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING AVG(salary) > 10000;
```

or

```
SELECT department_id, MAX(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING MAX(salary) > 10000;
```

run what you want...